# Should I even show up tomorrow, after being put on a Performance Improvement Plan?

Tags: resignation, canada, performance

I got put on a Performance Improvement Plan this afternoon. What would be the consequences of just putting my computer in a box for the courier and mailing it into my company?

I am a software developer in Canada.

Comment: Well what are the details dude? I mean did you deserve to get put on the PIP? What happened? Explain.

Comment: I assume Canada has jobless benefits. Find out if it matters if you quit or are fired in Canada or in to ur province if it varies.

Comment: I was once put on a PIP twice in the same job. I was never fired. Just do the PIP and be looking for a new job.

Comment: @dwjohnston, Great job.  It's good to know that positivity can help.

Comment: What does PIP stand for?

Comment: @Michael usually: Performance Improvement Plan, i.e. you're on notice that you're not doing well enough

Comment: Seems to me the clue is in the second word - "improvement" and therefore the answer to "what should I do?" is "improve" (assuming that the PIP was reasonable).

Comment: For you, the company or the person that decided to implement the PIP? I naturally presume you're asking about personal consequences for yourself, but the answer is very different in each situation. One would be a sign of immaturity, another would be embarrassing and the remainder would (possibly) be a loss. One grows more when facing tough situations than running from them.

Comment: @JonBentley One would assume this via use of common sense. But many of the questions here, including this one, show that it isn't particularly common.

Comment: @Michael PIP NORMALLY means not doing well... I've heard of companies that do it as a matter of course - so it COULD be not a bad thing. But generally it means company isn't happy with your performance and the path ahead is either a course correction on your part to fix the problems or a course correction on your part when you're let go after paperwork requirements have been met.

Comment: If you do something as immature as what you suggest, you are just confirming they are right to want to be rid of you as soon as possible. Do you really want the company to give you a reference that says "His response to criticism is to throw a tantrum like a spoiled two-year-old" - because that is what you will get.

Comment: @alephzero A company who put him on a PIP -- particularly those companies who use PIPs as a preamble to termination, which is common, as the answers point out -- are unlikely to provide OP references for future work, regardless.

Answer (score 54):

Show up, but assume you will be fired and put your main effort into getting the next job.  You show up so you continue to make a salary, and so that you can say you're still employed while searching for a job (which will make you both look more attractive as an employee and give you negotiating leverage if an offer is made).  Although taking one sick day to process things emotionally wouldn't necessarily be a bad idea.

Comment: "Although taking one sick day to process things emotionally wouldn't necessarily be a bad idea." This!!! if you find yourself emotionally unstable, which I think is very humane, cause when I feel overstressed or overwhelmed. Rash decision by emotion often fails me so many times.

Comment: "assume you will be fired" <--- This makes no sense. Why would the company put someone on a PIP if they're just going to fire them

Comment: @Persistence Because in some work environments, that's part of the process. Regulations (be they imposed by law or by union contracts or self-imposed) might prevent to fire someone without good reasons and documentation that those reasons exist. A personal improvement plan is a method to construct such reasons and document them.

Comment: The pip is indeed often the corridor towards the exit door...

Comment: @Persistence - the PIP may be, as mentioned by others, a necessary part of the firing process.  In many cases, if they want you to improve, they (usually this means your direct boss) will work with you without this formal process, to encourage you to improve.  That said, some companies may use the PIP to encourage improvement, though I do not remember having seen this in action.

Comment: @Persistence Legal cover in case of lawsuit for a variety of reasons (discrimination, hostile work environment, etc).  Just in case they need it.  A PIP is 99% of the time legal cover and 1% of the time them actually hoping you improve.  And that ratio may be generous.

Comment: @Philipp at least you're employed and being paid during the process.  If you walk out, you've possibly given them what they need to fire you, or possibly resigned without giving notice.  Taking some sort of legitimate time off may or may not be advisable.

Comment: @ChrisH I didn't dispute that.

Answer (score 23):

> Should I even show up tomorrow?

Yes, you should show up at work tomorrow if you have not got a new job offer yet, and if you still need the paychecks to pay the bills. Even if you no longer love this current job, it still is a source of income.

While you are working for this company on PIP, please make sure to look for a new job outside work hours.

If you quit now, it may be awhile till you get a good job offer in this COVID time as you know. So, it is a good idea to hang on to this current job as long as you can while actively looking for a better job.

I don't see why you should quit right away tomorrow unless the work environment is too hostile or toxic, and causes you tremendous stresses that significantly affect your mental and physical health.

Comment: Also, while you are looking for a new job, make sure to learn your lessons so that you never repeat whatever earned you the PIP in the first place. Getting fired once is kinda bad, getting fired twice in a row for the same reason is a disaster.

Comment: "If you quit now, it may be awhile till you get a good job offer in this COVID time as you know." - If it wasn't hard enough to find a job, it will be even tougher to find that job, when ask "so why did you leave your last position?";  You can try to omit the reason you left, but that only works until the hiring manager from Company A, doesn't know somebody from current company.

Answer (score 11):

In many cases, a PIP is a thinly veiled information gathering to build a file to fire you for cause.  Unless your company is has a history of people surviving PIPs, your chances are slightly better chance than computing the last digit of Pi in your head.

That said, go to work, do your job, and follow the PIP to the LETTER and give them no excuse to fire you.  You want to survive this long enough to find another job.  Politics is the art of saying "nice doggy" while looking for a rock.

The ideal situation would be if you could manage to survive the PIP to completion as some companies will ask if you are currently on a PIP, and that will kill your application, but don't bet on surviving, get out ASAP.

In the future, look for the warning sigs of an impending PIP:

- Bad feedback or no feedback
- Left out of conversations
- Coworkers refusing to grant assistance
- Left out of group meetings
- Reduced responsibilities
- General feeling of getting the "cold shoulder"

Comment: What do you mean by *Politics is the art of saying "nice doggy" while looking for a rock.*?  That sounds quite cruel.

Comment: Your first paragraph is greatly exaggerated. There are many companies where it's quite possible to survive a PIP. For example, I recently read that, at one major tech company, "more than one-third" of its employees on PIPs failed those PIPs and left the company. To be sure, a more-than-one-third-chance of losing your job is very high; but it's nowhere *near* as high as the chance that you can't calculate the last digit of *π*.

Comment: Indeed, I have worked for a company where they viewed a PIP as an opportunity to find the evidence to SAVE you, not fire you. After all, they've invested a lot in hiring, training, coaching you over the years, and they want to maximize that return if possible.

Comment: @corsiKa of course it varies with company and national culture; I also have seen people  come out the other side in the same job, though they were first to be got rid of in a round of redundancies a few years later (sadly, in one case, after he'd become really useful).  Demotion is also a possible outcome in some places.

Comment: @gerrit https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/12/18/diplomacy/ ; the implication is that the "nice doggie" is in fact a serious threat to you

Comment: @JoeStrazzere In that case, if you were already legally covered and did not need the PIP as additional documentation, did you/your company ever consider skipping the PIP and firing right away? That would save the salary during the PIP. You could even give (part of) that salary as a severance payment and come out ahead, rather than having the ineffective employee continue in a futile slog with an inevitable outcome.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere you're a living legend, so of course you do things the right way.

Comment: @nanoman also by being graceful, you're improving your chances of an orderly handover if the situation doesn't mean getting them out of the building immediately.

Comment: @gerrit It's a Will Roger's quote.  The threat is implicit as nobody needs to say "nice doggy" unless the dog is a threat.  It also doesn't imply that the rock will be thrown, only as a way to defend yourself .  also, it's not literally

Answer (score 7):

**Canada Specific Answer**

If you want to be eligible for EI benefits while looking for your next job, you must meet [these criteria](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/ei/ei-regular-benefit/eligibility.html) (emphasis mine):

> - were employed in insurable employment
> - **lost your job through no fault of your own**
> - are affected by flooding or wildfires
> - have been without work and without pay for at least seven consecutive days in the last 52 weeks
> - have worked for the required number of insurable employment hours in the last 52 weeks or since the start of your last EI claim, whichever is shorter [Temporary COVID-19 relief](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/ei/ei-regular-benefit/eligibility.html#covid19-changes)
> - are ready, willing and capable of working each day
> - are actively looking for work (you must keep a written record of employers you contact, including when you contacted them)

So if you keep showing up and end up getting fired before finding a new job, at least you'll be able to maintain some income. If you stop showing up and you're fired for not showing up, you're waiving your eligibility to receive support from the government while you look for your next job.

Comment: +1 for Canada specific answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should show up. There are people advising for you to try and salvage your current job, and if at all possible, I advise it too.

But, it sounds like that at this point, you sound 110% done with your job. We don't know the circumstances, but your goal is to MANAGE YOUR SITUATION and transition into your next role, and maintaining your current role for as long as possible is what you should do.

1. Continue to work and contribute the best you can so you can continue to make a paycheck. Being unemployed is expensive, having the least amount of time between jobs is the best.
2. Finding new employment is much easier while you are employed, start applying while your resume still says your job is "current"
3. Salvage whatever relationships you can from this place. There's no need to completely burn the ship down, with some humility, try to reconcile with whoever you can. Maintaining good relationships is important, you have no idea who knows who.
4. Talk to several people you trust most and ask them if you can use them as a reference. Maybe there are a few people who are sympathetic to your situation and can be used for references in the future. If you can downplay that you are currently applying, the better, as you don't want rumors of you trying to leave after being placed on a PIP.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, you should not only turn up, but put in 110%.

Yes, you should turn up. The point of a Performance Improvement Plan is to, well, improve your performance. Your performance has not been at a satisfactory level to date, and they're giving you a step-by-step plan on how to get your performance to an appropriate level.

So, given that, not only should you aim to meet those goals, but you should aim to exceed them. If those goals are the minimum level you need to reach for your performance to be considered acceptable, you should go even further beyond to reach the level where your performance would be considered "good". If that means you put in overtime, you put in overtime. If that means you spend your weekends studying courses, you study those courses on the weekends. If that means after you go home you spend your evenings preparing for the next day's work, then you stay up until midnight preparing.

You can worry about burnout after the Performance Improvement Plan period's over.

Comment: This is not always the case. Even if you go above and beyond, they might renew the PIP. For how long can you manage burnout-style conditions? Also “they're giving you a step-by-step plan on how to get your performance to an appropriate level” — isn’t always the case either. They may just give you expectations, and not provide guidance on how to effectively accomplish them.

Comment: I agree with @Erika, and I would go a little further, perhaps -- they may just give you expectations, and give such confusing feedback that it is not possible to accomplish them.  On the other hand, if they do give you clear and practical feedback, use it.  Even if you do not survive the trial period, and you get fired, the improvements will help at your next job.

Comment: *They may just give you expectations, and not provide guidance on how to effectively accomplish them.* - I would agree;  Only the author can determine if their PIP, has goals, but no measurable way of how to achieve those goals.  Although I would argue that discussion should be happening daily, with their manager, or as often as is required to achieve the goals.